# DateTime in SQL Server CE query?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-ce

I have a date and time I'd like to insert into a SQL Server CE database, I'm trying to follow the string format `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss` but I get an invalid token exception when I try to insert it.

If the format is just `dd-MM-yyyy` everything is fine but I need to be able to add the time of day too...

Comment: could you share your codes?

Comment: Why don't you use a parameter of `DateTime` type, please avoid passing it as string

Comment: How does your php input for date and time look like?

Comment: If you're building a string at all, you're already doing it wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is always preferable to use Parameters:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@newTimeStamp", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = timeStamp;
```